# Кнопка добавляет в ссылку post запрос

Tags: javascript, html

сделал pop up форму для отправки заявки, имеются 2 кнопки к ним, открытия и закрытия формы. Реализовал через JS функции и onClick на кнопках.

Проблема заключается в том, что когда кнопка закрытия активируется страница перезагружается и меняет ссылку страницы в браузере с доп. запросом, например оригинальная ссылка "/lang/index_ru.html" а меняется на "/lang/index_ru.html?category_order=". Понял что кнопка зачем-то добавляет название тега select, но почему и зачем нет. Прошу помочь знающих!

```
<div class="popup_containter" id="popup_containter">
<div class="popup_inner">
    <form class="order_form" action="">
        <button onclick="popup_form_cancel()"><img src="../img/icons_svg/cancel_icon.svg" alt=""></button>
        <p>Оформить заказ</p><br>
        <input class="wht_lght" type="text" name="" id="name" placeholder="Имя"><br>
        <select class="wht_lght" name="category_order" id="order_type" placeholder="Категория товара">
            <option value="">Категория товара</option>
            <option value="">Бытовая техника</option>
            <option value="">Электронная техника</option>
            <option value="">Одежда</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input class="wht_lght" type="tel" name="" id="phone_number" placeholder="Номер телефона">
        <input class="wht_lght anim_but_wht" type="submit" value="Отправить">
    </form>
</div>
```

```
function popup_form(){
    var popup_order = document.getElementById("popup_containter");
    popup_order.classList.add("active");
}

function popup_form_cancel(){
    var popup_order = document.getElementById("popup_containter");
    popup_order.classList.remove("active");
}
```

Comment: в приведенном вами html отсутствует тег ссылки `<a>`. Суть вопроса не ясна.

Comment: ссылку страницы в браузере

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пропишите `<button type="button">`, должно помочь. По умолчанию у кнопки `type="submit"` вы по нажатию пытаетесь отправить форму.